# ChannelInterceptorAdapter is deprecated - what is the replacement?

Tags: spring

I'm using spring and I get a warning that `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` is deprecated. I'm having trouble figuring out what the replacement class is.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Java 8 added the concept of default methods in interfaces, so the Spring team updated the framework to make full use of the new Java language features. 
 https://www.baeldung.com/web-mvc-configurer-adapter-deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Use implement ChannelInterceptor directly if using Java8 and above.